# Writing a setup.py file for local use of a python package

Tags: python, local, setup.py

I'm developping an application for an embedded device. I have some customized libraries on my PC that I want to add to Buildroot to include them in my Linux image that is to be run on the device. I am creating `setup.py` files for each of them, as they are required by Buildroot, but I don't know how exactly to replace the usual `url` and `download_url` fields. Should I write something like `url="<path to my library>"` ? or replace the fields by some others ? Can anyone tell me ?

Thank you !

I used the `setup.py` model from [this tutorial,](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56) in case you would like to know.

Comment: I use GitHub links for the projects, but not sure if it is correct and good to use.

Comment: AFAIK, they are only informative fields. You can try to omit them or put something like `'__NON_EXISTENT__'` if they are required.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed I tried and omitting it doesn't raise any error ! I thought they were required (that's what is written on Python documentation) but seems like it's not the case ! Thank you !